# How to format static text in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

myText.buttonMode = true;

var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
myFormat.size = 24;

myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
```

Here `myText` is the instance name of the MovieClip of static text. How do I format static text in Flash CS6?

Answer (score 0):

[`setTextFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29) is a method of the [`TextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) class, **not** of the [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) class. You should call that method on a `TextField`, possibly the one in that `MovieClip`, that you named `myText`.

If you are wondering why you do not receive an error for calling a method that doesn't exist on your `MovieClip`: This is because `MovieClip` is a dynamic class.